# Use fastify-redis from controllers in node.js

Tags: node.js, caching, plugins, redis, fastify

How to use fastify-redis plugin from other controllers or other.js while declaring the redis connection in server.js

**server.js**

```
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: false })
const routes = require('./routes')

fastify.register(require('fastify-redis'), { host: '127.0.0.1' })

routes.forEach((route, index) => {
    fastify.route(route)
})

const start = async () => {
    try {
        await fastify.listen(3000)
        fastify.log.info(`server listening on ${fastify.server.address().port}`)
        //const { redis } = fastify
        //console.log(redis)
    } catch (err) {
        fastify.log.error(err)
        process.exit(1)
    }
}
start()
```

**Controller -> books.js**

```
exports.getBooks = async (request, reply) => {

    //console.log(redis)
    let data = {
        book: 'Book 1',
        author: 'Author 1'
    }

    //return data
    return redis.get('key1') // Not Defined
    //return redis.get('key1')
}
```

So, simply how can I use the Redis instance in other files to set some values in Redis as a to implement caching database data.

Comment: still you want this ?

Answer (score 3):

If you write your handler with a simple `function` (aka no arrow function), the `this` object will be binded to the fastify server:

```js
exports.getBooks = async function (request, reply) {
    console.log(this)
    let data = {
        book: 'Book 1',
        author: 'Author 1'
    }
    return this.redis.get('key1')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would do something like this: basically passing `app` instance over to the exported function in route that are used to bootstrap routes.

in route

```js
module.exports = fastify => [
    {
        url: '/hello',
        method: 'GET',
        handler: async (request, reply) => {
            const { redis } = fastify
            // ...
        }
    },
    {
        url: '/hello',
        method: 'POST',
        handler: async (request, reply) => {
            const { redis } = fastify
            // ...
        }
    }
]
```

and bootstraping routes at start

```js
app.register(plugin1)
    .register(plugin2)
    .after(() => {
        // bootstraping routes
        // route definition should either be done as a plugin or within .after() callback
        glob.sync(`${__dirname}/routes/*.js`, { cwd: __dirname })
            .map(f => path.resolve(__dirname, f))
            .forEach(file => {
                const routeConfigs = require(file)(app)
                for (let i = 0; i < routeConfigs.length; i += 1) {
                    const routeConfig = routeConfigs[i]
                    app.route(routeConfig)
                }
            })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Send instances of fastify to `decorateRequest` when calling .after () then you will be able to use `redis` when calling `request` in the route handler.

Comment: Could you please provide a code example @rabbitman